# Empty cart before adding to cart specific products in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, hook-woocommerce

I have this code to empty the cart before adding new item to the cart.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'woocommerce_clear_cart_url' );

function woocommerce_clear_cart_url() {
    global $woocommerce;
    $woocommerce->cart->empty_cart();
}
```

But I want to limit this function to product id 986 and 1146. I mean when ever the customer add product id 986 or 1146, empty the cart first!

please help me i am totally noob

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following which will empty cart before whenadding to cart product Ids **`986`** or **`1146**`:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'custom_empty_cart', 10, 3 );
function custom_empty_cart( $passed, $product_id, $quantity ) {
    if( ( ! WC()->cart->is_empty() ) && in_array( $product_id, [986, 1146] ) )
        WC()->cart->empty_cart();

    return $passed;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Its possible do the same but with specific category? But not if the product its from this category.

Comment: @jose I don't catch sorry…